# How to wrap an event emitter with a Promise less weird-like?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying to wrap [http.get](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) with a `Promise`. Here's what I've got:

```
import Http from 'http';

export function get(url) {
    let req;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        req = Http.get(url, async res => {
            if(res.statusCode !== 200) {
                return reject(new Error(`Request failed, got status ${res.statusCode}`));
            }
            let contentLengthStr = res.headers['content-length'];
            if(contentLengthStr) {
                let contentLength = parseInt(contentLengthStr, 10);
                if(contentLength >= 0 && contentLength <= 2*1024**3) {
                    let buf = Buffer.allocUnsafe(contentLength);
                    let offset = 0;
                    res.on('data', chunk => {
                        if(chunk.length + offset > contentLength) {
                            return reject(new Error(`Received too much data, expected ${contentLength} bytes`));
                        }
                        chunk.copy(buf, offset);
                        offset += chunk.length;
                    });
                    res.on('end', () => {
                        if(offset === contentLength) {
                            resolve(buf);
                        } else {
                            return reject(new Error(`Expected ${contentLength} bytes, received ${offset}`));
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    return reject(new Error(`Bad Content-Length header: ${contentLengthStr}`));
                }
            } else {
                return reject(new Error(`Missing Content-Length header not supported`));
            }
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        req.abort();
        throw err;
    })
}
```

It seems to work OK, but it feels a bit clunky.

Firstly, `async`/`await` appear to be of no help here. I can't throw nor return inside of `res.on('end'`. Returning just returns out of the `end` callback, but there's no real way for me to break out of the `Http.get(url, res => {` function from inside there. `throw`ing doesn't "bubble up" to the Promise I created either because the `data`/`end` events don't fire synchronously. I have to call `reject` manually.

The part that really bothers me though is that if the server sends me more data than they said they were going to send me via the `Content-Length` header, I want to abort the request and stop listening for events. To do that I've rejected the Promise, and then immediately catch it so that I can abort the request, and then I rethrow the error so that the caller can handler it. To do this I have to declare the `req` variable above the Promise, and then initialise it inside the Promise, so that I can access it after the Promise.

The flow of everything just feels really clunky. Is there a nicer way to write this? (Assume I have available all ES6/ES2017+/next features)

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would approach the problem:

- "promisify' `Http.get`, meaning converting the API to use promises.
- Separate the stream logic into its own separate promise.
- Instrument the error logic in a clear flat async function.

This looks something like the following:

```
import Http from 'http';

// promisify Http.get
const http = (url, abort) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let req = Http.get(url, res => {
    if(res.statusCode !== 200) reject(new Error(`Request failed, got status ${res.statusCode}`));
    else resolve(res);
  });
  abort(() => req.abort()); // allow aborting via passed in function
});

export async function get(url) {
    let abort = null;
    let res = await http(url, (onabort) => { abort = onabort; });
    let contentLengthStr = res.headers['content-length'];
    if(!contentLengthStr) new Error(`Missing Content-Length header not supported`);
    if(contentLengthStr < 0 || contentLengthStr > (2*1024**3 +1)) {
      throw new Error(`Bad Content-Length header: ${contentLengthStr}`);
    }
    try { 
      return await read(res, contentLength);
    } catch (e) {
      abort();
      throw e;
    }
}

function read(res, contentLength) {
  let buf = Buffer.allocUnsafe(contentLength), offset = 0;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    res.on('data', chunk => {
      if(chunk.length + offset > contentLength) {
          return reject(new Error(`Received too much data, expected ${contentLength} bytes`));
      }
      chunk.copy(buf, offset);
      offset += chunk.length;
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
      if(offset === contentLength) resolve(buf);
      else return reject(new Error(`Expected ${contentLength} bytes, received ${offset}`));
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: You might want to even put the `if (res.statusCode !== 200)` logic outside the promisification

Comment: The way you threaded the abort through looks a bit strange, but I get it. Too bad Promises don't support aborting. Otherwise I like the way you split this out, hadn't considered that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Technically this should be on code review, but it's a different audience.

First observation. Correct me if I am wrong, but `HTTP.get` does not document usage of a return value from the call back. So unless function code uses the `await` keyword, leaving the callback defined with the `async` keyword is confusing (you did mention it was of no help).

A second source of confusion for readers is usage of the `return reject( ...... );` construct. `reject` doesn't return a value, and I am unaware of the return value of event listeners being used. So the the order can be reversed by placing the `return` statement (if actually needed) *after* the `reject` call.

Aborting the request can be done in scope of the promise executor by moving `let req;` back into the executor and explicitly calling `.abort` as required. Catching the promise should no longer be required. Refactored, the event emitter callbacks could, for example, look like

```
res.on('data', chunk => {
    if(chunk.length + offset > contentLength) {
        reject(new Error(`Received too much data, expected ${contentLength} bytes`));
        req.abort();
    } else {
        chunk.copy(buf, offset);
        offset += chunk.length;
    }
});
res.on('end', () => {
    if(offset === contentLength) {
        resolve(buf);
    } else {
        reject( new Error(`Expected ${contentLength} bytes, received ${offset}`));
        req.abort();
    }
});
```

Which just leaves the last two `return reject....` usages. You could either abort the request in each case, or set an `error` variable which is checked later:

```
    req = Http.get(url, res => {
        let error = null;
        // ....
            } else {
                error = new Error(`Bad Content-Length header: ${contentLengthStr}`);
            }
        } else {
            error = new Error(`Missing Content-Length header not supported`));
        }
        if( error) {
            reject( error);
            req.abort();
        }
    });
```

At this stage catching promise rejection and re-throwing the error should no longer be needed. Naturally this is untested but hopefully provides some useful feedback.

Comment: `return reject( ...... );` is commonly used to both `reject()` and prevent further execution in that block.  It's just a shortcut for putting the `return` statement on a separate line.  There is no harm in returning `undefined` which is what this will do.

Comment: @jfreiend00 personally I found the return in the "shortcut" required unnecessary  thinking about to determine it was mostly harmless.

Comment: It's only unnecessary if you add the `else` which the OP did not have.  As the OP had it a `return` is required to keep other code in the block from executing.  So now, you're just debating an early return vs. an else clause - two different styles of achieving the same thing.  No right or wrong, just opinion (which as you say would be more appropriate in code review, not here).

Comment: I forgot to remove the `async` ever realizing I couldn't utilize it. I could inline the `abort`, but I'm just not sure from the documentation if other kinds of errors will leave the connection open or not. If anything goes wrong, I'd rather abort/close the connection immediately which is why I did I just abort on any error. Catching it seemed cleaner than repeating `req.abort()` everywhere. Forgot there was a a codereview.stackexchange; thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Probably late, but just wanted to clarify something: If we do return reject(..); then it gets handled in the .then(...) and not .catch(…). However when I do just resolve() or reject(), they come to .then and .catch respectively. Is it the way it should behave or am I missing something. If it is fine, then how do we discontinue the function once resolve or reject, as they are not control variables.

Comment: @tanmayghosh2507 Please ask a separate question about your experience, detailing how to reproduce the issue. If you actually reject a promise, it should never get handled by an onfulfilled handler attached to the same promise.